CMake Error: Could not find a package configuration file provided by "oatpp"
I am trying to build the oatpp-sqlite module using CMake on Windows with Visual Studio 2022. I have successfully installed oatpp version 1.3.0 and set up my environment as follows:

oatpp installation directory: C:\Users\Aditya\oatpp\oatpp-1.3.0-latest

Visual Studio version: Visual Studio 17 2022

CMake version: [add your CMake version]


When I run the cmake .. command in the build directory of oatpp-sqlite, I get the following error:
-- Building for: Visual Studio 17 2022
-- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.22621.0 to target Windows 10.0.22631.
-- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.40.33808.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.40.33808.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.40.33807/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.40.33807/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
Finding oatpp in location=INSTALLED
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:52 (find_package):
  By not providing "Findoatpp.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "oatpp", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "oatpp" (requested
  version 1.3.0) with any of the following names:

    oatppConfig.cmake
    oatpp-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "oatpp" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "oatpp_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "oatpp"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

I have tried adding the oatpp installation path to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH using the following command:
cmake .. -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=C:\Users\Aditya\oatpp\oatpp-1.3.0-latest  

But it did not resolve the issue. How can I properly configure CMake to find the oatpp package?

Is C:\Users\Aditya\oatpp\oatpp-1.3.0-latest an installed copy of oatpp or is it just the source code? If its not an installed copy then it wont have the cmake config file which is generated when building the install target

In oatpp-1.3.0-latest\build\src i have oatppConfig.cmake file but still it gives me same error

Did you set CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH to oatpp-1.3.0-latest\build\src?

Yes set it but the cause of issue was different i solve that issue it's happened because i don't run commands with administrative privileges so that why issue cause when i install oatpp with administrative privileges it's fine now
